# key doesn't turn smoothly in the ignition

Tags: toyota, ignition, ignition-key, yaris

I have a 2014 Toyota Yaris LE automatic. I have noticed lately when I insert the key and turn to start the car it's a bit rough not smooth as it used to be. The key turns no problem and the car starts, but the feeling is not the same i hear a sound also when turning the key as if you scratching something against a rough surface. My knowledge when it comes to cars is really limited, I was hoping someone explains to me If I should be worried and what causes such an issue, if it's a real issue what i should be doing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance and Repair!

Comment: Is there any way you could get some audio of the noise? Your description is very limited and some audio or video (w/ audio) would most likely go a long ways so we can help you.

Comment: Is the rough sound coming from the engine, or is it just the feel of the ignition cylinder that feels rough

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I will try to record the sound if possible, it's more the feeling of the key when i turn it in the ignition than the sound but i will try. apology my English is not helping me describe the problem.

Comment: @user38183 not the engine, it;s the feel of the ignition when i turn the key to start the car